# How to run a .desktop file on login in Ubuntu 16.04 Mint CInnamin

Tags: login, .desktop

I have found multiple tutorials for running a .desktop file on startup. One problem, They are all for old versions of ubuntu and do not work on Ubuntu 16.04. If I need clarification or anything just leave a comment

```
cat Minecraft_Server.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Launch the Minecraft Server
Terminal=true
Name=Minecraft_Server
Exec=/home/sam/MineServer/Start_Server.sh
Type=Application
Icon=/home/sam/MineServer/server-icon.png
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Startup apps is still used in 16.04 and newer. Doesn't it work for running your program?

Comment: No I have tried doing that and it does not work for some reason but if I directly execute the .Desktop file with nautilus it works just fine.

Comment: Desktop files you want started after you log in you can copy to `~/.config/autostart` folder.  Recommended the desktop file be owned by your user account and have a `664` permissions set on it.

Comment: Still did not work

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/918613/edit) your question and include more detail of what you're trying to do.  Run `cat` on your desktop file and include that as well.  There might be something in your desktop file that could be limited to the desktop environment where the line might read `OnlyShowIn=XFCE;` where you might be running `Unity`.

Comment: I'm confused, are you using Mint, or no?

Answer (score 1):

That can actually be done as a startup script instead.  Open *Settings -> Session and Startup*.  Go to `Application Autostart` tab.  Click `Add`, give it a name like `Minecraft Server` or something.  For the command line, add the following:

```
bash -c 'sleep 5; /home/sam/MineServer/Start_Server.sh'
```

[image]

Then click OK.

I like to put the sleep there so that the script does not try to start immediately after logging in as some applications might cause it not to start.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get a error saying "Unable to find Jar file SERVER.jar" Even though it exists. in the same folder

Comment: I have figured out the Issue even after using exact file locations (Starting with /) I had to be in the folder of the Server...